# How to load balance docker container servers

Tags: docker, server, containers, load-balancing

I have 2 servers that pop users into a docker shell when they ssh in with their username. What are some good ways I can add a load balancer to this system so users have one entry point? I have looked at nginx and haproxy but they all seem to focus on using Docker to host a web application. So I'm not quite sure if there is a service that allows me to load balance docker shells or I just have to do a manual load balancer based on system loads. Any thoughts?

Comment: In principle HAProxy can load-balance any TCP stream, but that also means you're not going to consistently get the same server for your interactive shells.